# Can't find HTML Snippet in Profiles (Drupal)

Tags: form-snippets

I want to use the HTML snippet.

But i don't find the path to active "Accept profile submissions from external sites to Yes".

i'm using CiviCRM 4.7.29 running with Drupal.

any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is available under **Misc (Undelete, PDFs, Limits, Logging, Captcha, etc.)** (CiviCRM >> Administer >> System Settings >> Misc (Undelete, PDFs, Limits, Logging, Captcha, etc.))

[image]

> Note: Try clearing CiviCRM cache if you still unable to see it under
>   Misc.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: once again, you save my life Pradeep, thank you ;-)

Comment: My pleasure... Cheerz (y)